# Hibernate: Too many queries for a One to One relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, one-to-one

**Short Version**

Hibernate is doing multiple select queries instead of only two to retrieve a one to one relationship

**Long Version**

Person Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @OneToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private Job job;
}
```

Job Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class Job{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String name;
}
```

Displaying all People and their Jobs:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<Person> people = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
for(Person p : people){
    System.out.println(p.getName() + " | " + p.getJob().getName());
}
```

What I expected: Two selects, one for the five People and one for their three different Jobs (three people have the same job)

What I got: Four selects, one for People and three for each of their different Jobs

```
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_, person0_.job_id as job3_1_, person0_.name as name1_ from people person0_
Hibernate: select job0_.id as id0_0_, job0_.name as name0_0_ from jobs job0_ where job0_.id=?
Hibernate: select job0_.id as id0_0_, job0_.name as name0_0_ from jobs job0_ where job0_.id=?
Hibernate: select job0_.id as id0_0_, job0_.name as name0_0_ from jobs job0_ where job0_.id=?
Jim | Programmer
Andrew | DBA
Tomas | Sysadmin
Henry | Sysadmin
Jerry | Sysadmin
```

If I had 1000 people with 1000 different jobs, I would see 1000 selects being executed. How can I make it so Hibernate only does two selects?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be Person - Job relationship `@ManyToOne`? Same job done by many people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example of the `n + 1` problem, for which the [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-custom)  suggests using the `JOIN` fetch mode. You can enable this with the hibernate-specific annotation

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a one-to-one relationship, you have a one-to-many relationship.  A job can have multiple people attached to it.  Hibernate is assuming that there is actually a one-to-one relationship and not noticing that three people are pointing at 1 job.
Then you have to solve the N+1 selects problem, as beerbajay points out.